# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Subreport Displayed multiple times in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have built a report and inserted a subreport into one of the columns.  The problem is that it is not matching data row by row instead it is rendering the subreport on each row. I have linked a picture to show the issue more clearly.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here. Can you update your question to include your report design(s) and a sketch of what you expect the output to look like along with any relevant things like how your subreport data relates to the main report.

Comment: you might be forget to remove the (Detail) group in your row grouping section. Kindly remove it and check.